# useContext duplicates the entries in the array in consumer component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm learning react context and while developing a todo application using useContext, I'm facing an issue where on submitting one task, the same task gets added two times to an array. The output component would loop through this array and display the results. While debugging I observed that, although the submit of task add only one entry into the array, not sure why and how, the consumer component gets the array with duplicate entry. Please let me know, what I'm missing.

Here is my code of index file that maintains context

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import ContextReducer, { initialState } from "./ContextReducer";

const taskContext = createContext();

const ContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ContextReducer, initialState);

  const setTaskInput = (taskInput) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_TASKINPUT",
      payload: taskInput,
    });
  };

  const addTask = (task) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TASK",
      payload: task,
    });
  };

  const deleteTask = (id) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "DELETE_TASK",
      payload: id,
    });
  };

  const todoContext = {
    todo: state.todo,
    taskInput: state.taskInput,
    setTaskInput,
    addTask,
    deleteTask,
  };

  return (
    <taskContext.Provider value={todoContext}>
      {props.children}
    </taskContext.Provider>
  );
};
export { taskContext };
export default ContextProvider;
```

This is the code for reducer

```
const initialState = {
  todo: [],
  taskInput: "",
};

const ContextReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === "SET_TASKINPUT") {
    state.taskInput = action.payload;
    return {
      todo: state.todo,
      taskInput: state.taskInput,
    };
  }
  if (action.type === "ADD_TASK") {
    state.todo = [...state.todo, action.payload];
    return {
      todo: state.todo,
      taskInput: state.taskInput,
    };
  }
  if (action.type === "DELETE_TASK") {
    state.todo = state.todo.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload);
    return {
      todo: state.todo,
      taskInput: state.taskInput,
    };
  }
  return state;
};

export { initialState };
export default ContextReducer;
```

This is the code of output component or say, consumer component

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext } from "react";
import { taskContext } from "../../Context";
import styles from "./Content.module.css";

const Output = () => {
  const { todo, deleteTask } = useContext(taskContext);

  const deleteHandler = (e) => {
    deleteTask(+e.target.parentElement.parentElement.id);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {todo.length > 0 && (
        <div className={styles.outputDiv}>
          <ul>
            {todo.map((task) => {
              return (
                <li key={task.id} id={task.id}>
                  <div className={styles.row1}>{task.task}</div>
                  <div className={styles.row2}>
                    <button className={styles.edit}>Edit</button>
                    <button className={styles.delete} onClick={deleteHandler}>
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Output;
```

Comment: Is this reproducible on production build ? This behavior should not reflect in production i.e. try building the app ```npm run build``` and test out the same section again.

Comment: @SARANSURYA, thanks for the reply. I will definitely try what you said, however, I want to know the reason for why is this happening

Comment: @SARANSURYA, you were right, after building the production build and running it, I see that everything is working fine. But, I want to know what mistake of mine caused this issue. I never came across such issue earlier

Comment: Hi @Akash it is due to the React.StrictMode. Here is a link to help you out. https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Comment: @SARANSURYA, yes, removing React.StrictMode worked. Thanks a lot